# Unsure of this HTML/CSS meaning

Tags: html, css

I've been doing some freelance html/css work, and lately I've come across a `div:class"innertube"` and its usually nested inside of a `div:id`. My question is what is an innertube and why is it used?

Comment: Are you trying to say you've come across `<div class="innertube">` nested inside another `div`?

Comment: correct, it looks something like this: 

 <div id="topsection">
  <div class="innertube">
   <h1>Layout 3</h1>
  </div>
 </div>

Comment: and in the css they dont have much for it like margin-10px; or something, I'm just curious what its purpose is, cause i've never seen the "inner tube" name before

Comment: Are you asking why the class name is "innertube" or are you asking if div:class"innertube" is valid syntax?

Comment: probably it's just the name of a css class that was used at some point but not is no longer used, or it's defined in some other file

Comment: I have no idea, class names don't have any intrinsic meaning attached to them, so it could be anything.

Comment: Were you by any chance looking at something relating to three-column liquid layouts?

Comment: "Were you by any chance looking at something relating to three-column liquid layouts?" I was yes, and in the code of several examples was the "inner tube". I was just wondering why it is named that and what does it do, if anything? Perhaps meaningless like ultranut suggested

Comment: I didn't say it was meaningless, I said it didn't have any *intrinsic* meaning. Big difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `class` attribute is used to distinguish between CSS, well, classes.  For example, if you have `<div class="outertube">` and `<div class="innertube">`, these two `div` elements would have different formatting applied to them.  It's up to the programmer to decide what names to give the classes.

http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#h-7.5.2